# Smart Door options

Tags: smart-home

I'm looking for a ready-to-use Smart Door in a room. I want to control it via app (Bluetooth or direct wifi is ok) or by voice commands. It should have the following skills:

- open
- close
- lock
- unlock

I tried googling this, but the problem is that I find a ton of *smart locks* (many click baits: smart locks referred as smart doors) and *garage doors*, but there's no smart door for a room.

Could you help me to find it?

Comment: I don't think what you want exists. Anything will be to fit to an existing door, because doors come in different sizes/shapes. Also do you mean by open/close to actually open the door not just synonyms for lock/unlock?

Comment: You have self-opening/closing doors in office buildings (mostly sliding doors) or e.g. hospitals/nursing homes. But I am pretty sure those are not directly sold to the end customer.

Comment: Nowadays, anyone can generally buy from trade stores.But the price for such doors will make your eyes water